# Identifying a ceramic capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I'm having trouble to identify this bad boy:

[image: cap]

'680' or '089' i don't even know how to read it.
Can someone give me the value ?

I used a Chinese T4 LCR on it and according to the result the value is 61/62 pF

What the difference between this next capacitor (except value) and the previous one if there is any?

[image: cap2]

Comment: 680 is a standard value, 68*(10**0) pF. 089 is not.

Comment: +/- 10% is a reasonably normal tolerance for capacitors. Not accounting for the meter you used. 68pF is what I would expect from the print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your LCR is not lying to you (much).
680 translates to **68**x10<sup>**0**</sup> and is given in units of pf.
So 680 = 68pF

There is no difference in capacitance value between those 2 examples, they're both 68pF but the orange/brown one doesn't explicitly specify the 0.

Comment: Reference: for aluminum electrolytics (and tantalums, I suppose), the value is usually in microfarads.